# Convert my raw data counts from sensor into a float to scale the values

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c

I am trying to scale my raw integer counts from a pressure sensor that ranges from `(81 to 16209)` to real pressure in cmH2O that ranges from `(-351.54 to 351.54)` by using this equation `(((rawValue - 81) * 702.0 / 16128.0) - 351.0)`. I am ok with converting it to -351 to 351 without the decimal if that makes the process any easier. I am using a PIC18F2580.

I have tried different methods but none have worked. Here is the section of the code that I am currently working on. When I read the (rawValue) function on my LCD it looks like excepted, but once I start doing the scaling all the numbers get messed up. The commented sections are the ways I have tried but no luck yet. Any ideas of how I could achieve my goal?

```c
I2C_Master_Start();
I2C_Master_Write(0x50);
I2C_Master_Write(0x01);
I2C_Master_RepeatedStart();
I2C_Master_Write(0x51);
rawHighByte = I2C_Master_Read(true); // Read the first byte and send an ACK
rawLowByte = I2C_Master_Read(false); // shift the previously read value into the upper byte 
I2C_Master_Stop();

// Calculate the pressure from the received data        
uint16_t rawValue = ((uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8) | rawHighByte;
   
// int newValue = ((rawValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin)) / (oldMax - oldMin) + newMin;
// uint16_t newValue = ((rawValue - 81) * 702.0 / 16128.0) - 351.0;
// uint16_t newValue2 = newValue - 351;
// uint16_t newValue3 = rawValue - 81;
// float sensor_data_float = (float)newValue3;
// float result = sensor_data_float * 702.0; // perform multiplication with float value

sprintf(pressure_str, "P: %d", rawValue);
lcd_clear();
```

Comment: If a count of `81` repesents `-351.54`, and a count of `16209` repesents `+351.54`, then the *scale* is `703.08 / (16209 - 81)` which is `0.04359375` and the zero point is `(16209 + 81) / 2` which is `8145`. The conversion is then `(count - 8145) * scale`. Test 1, `(81 - 8145) * 0.04359375` is `-351.54`. Test 2, `(16209 - 8145) * 0.04359375` is `351.54`.

Comment: Possibly an aside, but in this: `((uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8) | rawHighByte;`, either the variables are badly named, or you're shifting the wrong one.

Comment: @pmacfarlane, it's BE to LE conversion. Low byte here obviously means the first byte from bytesream that represents BE16 value. I don't see a big issue with a naming here.

Comment: When you say "none have worked" and "get messed up", you better describe what exactly goes on. Provide a [mcve] to make it clear. Else, people have to guess, so you will get worse answers (bad guess = no fun). I tried to guess and wrote an answer, but I am not sure at all I guessed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Type `uint16_t` holds non-negative values: the `u` there stands for "unsigned". Your values have sign, so you should use `int16_t` for these. But even better, use `float` - your values are not integers.

```
// Calculate the pressure from the received data        
uint16_t rawValue = ((uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8) | rawHighByte;

// Convert to [-351, 351] range   
float value = (((float)rawValue - 81.0f) * 702.0f / 16128.0f) - 351.0f;

sprintf(pressure_str, "P: %f", value);
```

Note: before calculations, the code above converts the value to `float`. Also, it uses the `f` suffix to mark all constants having type `float` (else, it would be `int` or `double` - you want neither of these).

To print a `float` value into a string, it uses `%f`.